# Define default return value/function of a class?

Tags: c#, .net

Can I create a class with a default return value? Lets say if I create an object of this class I get always a specific value, without calling the properties or something else. Example:

```
int i = new MyIntClass(/*something*/); //will return an int
```

Actually I would like to use a default function for returning something. Maybe like this:

```
class MyCalculator()
{
  public double a { get; set; }
  public double b { get; set; }

  MyCalculator(double a, double b)
  {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  public double DoMath()
  {
    return a*b;
  }
}

/* somewhere else */
double result = new MyCalculator(5.5, 8.7);
```

`result` should be the result of `DoMath()`. Is that possible? I know its maybe not the best example, but something like this would be nice. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with just calling a method?

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do? *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Just because its shorter. Lets say there is a class just for one thing: like in my example - just for calculating a*b. Why should people always write .DoMath()?

Comment: Because it makes it clearer what's going on. On the other hand, if it's just for calculating a*b, why should it be a publicly visible class rather than a single static method? (Or an extension on double, perhaps).

Comment: A class constructor can only return an instance of itself. What you appear to be attempting to do is to have a construct of one type result in the construction of an unrelated type. Even if this were possible, it is a bad idea. It would be confusing to anyone else including you after a very short period of time. Use a static method if you don't need an instance. Use an extension method if you really must, but again I would question why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do an implicit cast.

Example (add to class):

```
public static implicit operator double(MyCalculator c)
{
  return c.DoMath();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But it's a terribly bad idea.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: OP asked 'Is that possible?', so I gave it. It was not asked whether is was a good idea or not...

Comment: That's why I went for both - explained how to do it, and then said it was a bad idea :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Sure, how else does one learn? ;p Learning the hard way is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 4):

If I follow you, you want a `MyCalculator` to have a `double` it can be treated as. You can do this with an implicit cast operator overload. Put this in the definition of `MyCalculator`:

```
public static implicit operator double(MyCalculator m)
{
  return m.DoMath();
}
```

However, it somewhat hides what's going on (you called `new` and got a `double`) and if you're a heavy user of `var` you'll find it annoying because you have to then be explicit.

In all, only use `implicit` if you have a *very* strong justification for it. Indeed, only use `explicit` if you have a *very* strong justification for it, and only use `implicit` if you've an *extremely* strong justification.

A good guideline for anything to do with a class' interface is "how sensible or weird will this look to someone who never sees the source code?"